# Android Facebook SDK - How to log in as another user?

Tags: android, facebook, logout, facebook-graph-api

I am using the official Facebook SDK for Android in my app.

I have managed to log in successfully,
but the problem arises when I try to log in as another user:
I click on the link that says `Logged in as [name]... Not you?`
but my application proceeds anyway and posts to my wall...
(as if I have clicked "Allow")

I discovered that clicking on that link throws a facebook exception and retries the request,
so I tried putting a call to logout() in the catch clause.

That made it possible to log in as a **new** user,
but the next time I run the app,
again, the **old** user is logged-in...
(Logged in as [old_user]. Not you?)

My question is:
**Why does the first user's login persist forever

and how to properly handle a click on "Not You" link?**

My current solution is to always call `logout()` before `authorize()` method
but this forces the user to always have to enter his/her email/password
which is not acceptable either.

Comment: facebook sdk integration is a real headache these days to many programmer. I wonder when i am gonna see a simple and stable facebook sdk as it runs with tweaks now.

Comment: @Javanator I don't understand how is it possible that such an important function just doesn't work properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook access token is saved by SessionStore.
When loggin into Facebook, it will try to restore the access token from SessionStore.
So, I think you can explicitly call facebook.logout and SessionStore.clear() when user exit your application.

Comment: Could you please tell how too do that.